# Trying to get 0 or 1 in bitwise but get 64 or 32 instead

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Following an exercise and I am trying to obtain in an integer, whether a bit is 0 or 1 in a certain position.

Here is my code so far:

```
Console.WriteLine("input number");
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("input position");
int position = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int place = 1;
int bit = place << position;
Console.WriteLine(bit);
```

So the user inputs a number (the integer, lets say 10) then a bit position (lets say 5) and the program should tell me if or not the 5th bit (from the right) is a 0 or one.

However instead its telling me the value that bit represents (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 etc.)

I really am uncertain what i've missed, I went ahead and looked up the solution (which I realised did not need user input) and that gave me the same error.

```
int n = 35;
int p = 6; 
int i = 1; 
int mask = i << p;
```

The question, quote, says "Value of the bit on the position p in the number (0 or 1)." so it wants 0 or 1 as output. So I'm stumped, really need some help please. I may be overthinking things and missing something obvious but I've failed to find a solution.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the bit value vs. the `number` you read in... (`Console.WriteLine(bit);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = 35;
int p = 6; 
int i = 1; 
int mask = i << p;
```

At this point, you have the `mask == 64`, and `n == 35`. Now you need to check or apply the mask in some way. A good way to do this is with the [`&` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx), which is a bitwise AND. In the case of a mask with one bit set to `1` (like your `mask`), this will tell you whether `n` has that bit set to `1` or `0`.

```
int masked = n & mask;
// masked will be 0 or 64; since we want 0 or 1...
int result = masked != 0 ? 1 : 0;
// although I'd go with a bool if possible, because it makes more sense
bool boolResult = masked != 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need *bitwise* `AND` `&` operator

```
int place = 1;
int bit = place << position;

if((number & bit) == bit)  Console.WriteLine("{0}. bit is 1",position);
else Console.WriteLine("{0}. bit is 0", position);
```

Answer (score 0):

you do a bit shift: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/a1sway8w.aspx

i think you should test your bit with the following code:

```
if(valueToTest & 32 == 32) => Bit is active
```